# NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver not work in Xamarine.Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin

I have 2 apps, one is build by Xamarin, another it Xcode.

Now a add a Observer in Xamarin project.
  NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("NotificationFromDMT",NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew,(obj) => {
                Console.WriteLine("123");
            });

And I post notification in my Xcode project

[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationFromDMT" object:nil];

Then I find it not work, My Xamarin app can not get any notification!!!

Can somebody fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing any object, just sending a name-based (string) notification so use `NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial`:

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("NotificationFromDMT", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, (obj) => { 
            Console.WriteLine("123"); 
});
```